# Projectile velocity and the role of sin and cos

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Im trying to recreate a bubble shooter game ( you are a bubble in the center and you are shooting at enemies coming towards you ). But i cant seem to figure out the role of sin and cos, or the velocity in all of this. Can somebody try to explain this for me?

```
window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const angle = Math.atan2(
    event.clientY - canvas.height / 2,
    event.clientX - canvas.width / 2
  );

  const velocity = {
    x: Math.cos(angle) * 5,
    y: Math.sin(angle) * 5,
  };

  projects.push(
    new Projectile(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 5, "red", velocity)
  );
});
```

Comment: What library/system are you using or is Projectile something you have coded yourself? What does it do and what are projects? Could you put up a whole snippet (including the HTML) so we can grasp what is going on?

Comment: I would recommend you to watch this video on how to create such a game. HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript Game Tutorial. youtube.com/watch?v=eI9idPTT0c4